# How to make own simple, fast and secure PHP template without eval()?

Tags: php, security, templates

How to make own simple, fast and secure PHP MySQL template without `eval()` for MySQL record:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|  id | content                                                |
|--------------------------------------------------------------|
|  12 | Today is {date}<br />Current time {include 'time.php'} |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

`{date}` must return `echo date('l');` and time.php content is `<?php echo date('h:i A'); ?>`

**Expected result would be:**

> Today is Thursday
>  Current time 23:17 PM

Comment: use smypfony template.. don't reivent the whel

Comment: This has nothing to do with MySQL - it's simply a storage mechanism. You'd have the same problem if the text was stored in a flat file.

Comment: @yes123 - I asked how to build an own template, no Twig, Smarty and whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible trough `preg_replace`. Example for `include`:

```
function finclude($file){
    return include($file);
}

$str = "Today is {include 'date.php'}.";
echo preg_replace("/\{include '(.*)\'}/e", 'finclude("$1")', $str);
```

date.php:

```
<?php return date('jS \of F'); ?>, 2011
```

will return: `Today is 20th of July.`

Does anyone knows some better way (secure, speed performance) to do it without `/e`  `eval`?

Answer (score 0):

You can search your text with a regex, you can also use replace methods to have the desired effect.

To build a complicated template engine I would refer to twig or Smarty (or another) and see how they do it.